# Set of integers $X$ of cardinality $k$ that sums up to zero but other choices of $k$ numbers do not

Tags: number-theory

Suppose one wishes to create set $X$ that consists of distinct integers, all integers sum up to zero, and has cardinality of $k$. However, one also wishes to create $X$ such that when $k$ numbers are chosen from $X$ including repeated integers (or differently said: think of $X$ as an urn of $k$ balls, and we are picking $k$ balls from the urn, but after each ball is picked, that ball goes back into the urn, and then one picks another ball and so forth), there is no way such numbers sum up to zero except when all numbers chosen are distinct.

Is there a general way of finding such a set given $k$ and make the biggest number as small as possible?

Comment: I'm not getting your question. I assume $k$ is a finite cardinal, so there is only one "choice" of $k$ elements. Also, you've not specified whether one of the elements can be $0$. Finally, what do you mean by repeated integers, when they're all supposed to be distinct? You might want to give a couple of concrete examples for lower $k$ values.

Comment: So what I mean is: think of $X$ as an urn of $k$ balls, and we are picking $k$ balls from the urn, but after each ball is picked, that ball goes back into the urn, and then one picks another ball and so forth.

Comment: Yes, but one can pick the same number more than once.